# How to use firebug console.log to find jquery parent/children in a <ul>

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm just trying to print back to better understand how to move around the tree traversal using console.log.

When I click on a parent I'd like to print back it's children. I thought it would be easy as

```
console.log($(event.target).children());
```

I've tried to use

```
console.log($(event.target).children("ul li a"));
```

It gives me `[]`. I'm looking to print out the child's ID.

HTM:

```
<body>
<div class = "testButton">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id = "Button One"> Parent One </a>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#" id = "P1 child">P1 child</a> </li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#" id = "Button Two"> Parent Two </a>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#" id = "P2 child">P2 child</a> </li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#" id = "Button Three"> Parent Three </a>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#" id = "P3 child">P3 child</a> </li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#" id = "Button Four"> Parent Four </a>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#" id = "P4 child">P4 child</a> </li>
                </ul>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.testButton ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0; 
}

.testButton li {
    display: inline;
}

.testButton a {
    display: block;
    width: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0em auto .14em;
    padding: .1em .5em .1em .5em;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.upButton {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}

.overButton {
    background-color: #222; 
    color: #fff;
}

.outButton {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}

.clickButton {
    background-color: #F90;
    color: #222;
}
```

JS:

```
google.load('jquery', '1.6.2');
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    $(".testButton a").addClass("upButton");

    $(".testButton a").mouseover(function(event){
        $(event.target).removeClass("outButton").addClass("overButton");    
    });

    $(".testButton a").mouseout(function(event){
        $(event.target).addClass("outButton");
    });

    $(".testButton a").click(function(event){
        $(".testButton a").removeClass("clickButton");
        $(event.target).addClass("clickButton");
        $(this).blur();
        console.log($(event.target));
        console.log($(event.target).children());        
        console.log($(event.target).parent().children());
        console.log($(event.target).siblings());
    });
});
```

Comment: This gets me closer...
    console.log($(event.target).next());

Comment: I think I found the answer, but is this really the way to find if the parent has a child? console.log($(event.target).next().find("li a"));

Comment: raym0nd and svick, I see that you made an edit, but what did you edit? Apologize, new to the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for the structure of your ul/li/a tags.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8Dn9/)

For the demo I have just simply alerted the ids for you. You can change these to console.log if you like. So now what I did...

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').children().each(function() {
        alert($(this).children('a').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

I added a class 'button' to each of your parents just to make it clear. So now when any item with a class 'button' is clicked, we get the next 'ul' in your html structure - (`next()` gets the next element at the same hierachy level of your code). Then for each child within that 'ul' I have alerted the id of each anchor within each child (as your structure is `<li><a id="..."></li>`).

Comment: Spencerooni: I only get a print back on the P1 and not the others. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean you only get a printed back 'P1' with your sample code using the function I provided? Your sample code only has one child of each parent, or have you changed it since? If you change the demo I provided to what you're using and click update, you should be able to share the current state of your code.